# C# Array Property in COM Interface?

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, interface, com

I am rewriting an Application that was formerly in Delphi using C#. It must **provide an Out-of-Process COM Server** that has the **exact same interfaces as the Delphi implementation**.
The Delphi Implementation of the COM Server takes advantage Array Properties that use strings as an index.
The Array Properties are accessed by the COM Clients (mostly written in VBA) in the following way:

```
X = Obj.Member(“FirstName”)             // get
Obj.Member(“FirstName”) = “John”        // put
```

There is **no possibility in changing the syntax** of these calls.

My Question is now:

### How can I Implement the Array Property in a C# Interface (COM)?

**Further Information:**

I have **tried to implement an Indexed Property** in C#, this works out for the CoClass but I have not found any way how I can embed this into an Interface (since No Fields are allowed) - and for the COM Interfaces I need to use an Interface.

The TypeLibrary file (.tlb) is available and the Generated IDL code for a Delphi Array Property looks like this:

```
[id(0x00000001), propget]
VARIANT Member([in] VARIANT Index);
[id(0x00000001), propput]
void Member(
              [in] VARIANT Index,
              [in] VARIANT rhs);
```

So, mainly it seems to translate the Array Property into **two different methods with the same ID**, one having the **attribute propget** and the other **propput**.
As far as I know, it is not possible to set these attributes manually in C#.
Using tlbimp.exe on the existing TLB, the disassembly of the created DLL looks like this:

```
[DispId(1)] (…CLR Stuff…)
object get_Member([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct), In] object Index);
[DispId(1)] (…CLR Stuff…)
void set_Member([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct), In] object Index, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct), In] object Value);
```

I have **tried to implement similar structure** (same DispID).
When using regasm.exe /tlb however the Method ID’s differ in the generated tlb. Also I **can't access the methods by using Obj.Member**.

I also tried giving the Methods the same Name as well as DispID. this works for the Get but nor for the put.

Generally I wouldn’t even need the Type library. I’m happy when the COM Clients can access the COM Server in the specified way.

Do you know how I can Implement the Array Property in a C# Interface (COM)?

Comment: `I have tried to implement an Indexed Property in C#, this works out for the CoClass but I have not found any way how I can embed this into an Interface` What's the problem here? You can certainly include an indexer in an interface. Something like: `int this[string val] { get; set; }` should be fine in an interface.

Comment: thank you for the answer. yes, this would work out fine if I would want to access the Object in form of `Obj("key") = "somevalue"` but since I need to access `Obj.Member("key") = "somevalue"` , the Member would then need to be a field of the Interface. This seems not possible in C#. Or do I missunderstand something here?

Comment: Well then whatever type `Member` is would need to have an indexer.

Comment: I have tried making a class - lets call it MemberClass. It uses an indexed property and works exactly how I would need it if used as a field in another class (its callable by `OtherClass.Member["index"]` ... However, it seems not possible to use the MemberClass as a field in a COM Interface, since Interfaces can not have fields.

Comment: This is a well-known restriction in C#.  Either use VB.NET to declare the interface or continue using the original type library.  The latter is the Smart Way, you can't break existing client code that way.